# ¿Cómo hago para que me funcione palindromo en un string? En Java

Tags: java

Buenas tengo que usar el método `reverse()` para que el `string` "anita lava la tina" se puede leer del mismo modo si lo doy vuelta.

Por el momento hice esto:

```
String frase = "anita lava la tina";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(frase);
String palindromoAlReves = builder.reverse().toString();
System.out.println(palindromoAlReves);
```

Y como salida sale esto:
**anit al aval atina**

Cuando tendría que salir así:
**anita lava la tina**

¿Cómo puedo hacer que funcione de forma correcta?

Comment: Se me ocurre que tendrías que quitarle los espacios, hacer el reverse y volverle a colocar los espacios en el lugar que estaban.\

Comment: El código es correcto, funciona para palabras sin espacio ejemplo `anilina`, pero lo que debes hacer es eliminar los espacios en la palabra, realizar el reverse, y luego validar si en cada posición la letras son iguales. Esto determinara que la palabra en cuestión es palindroma.

Comment: Hola. tienes la frase  "anita lava la tina" y quieres obtener la frase  "anita lava la tina",me parece que no tiene mucho sentido, lo aconsejable es determinar si es o no palíndroma tu frase, que opinas @computer96 ?

Comment: Bueno al final lo que hice fue quitarle los espacios a esa frase y ahi si me va a dar igual. Gracias a todos por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que hay un pequeño malentendido, la definición de una frase o palabra palíndroma es:

> [palíndroma](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pal%C3%ADndromo) es una palabra, o frase que se lee igual adelante que
>   atrás

Por lo tanto a partir de la frase:

```
anita lava la tina
```

si "normalizamos" quitando espacios y la invertimos obtenemos

```
anitalavalatina
```

se lee similar a la frase original, esto indica que es una frase palíndroma.

---

En realidad no tiene mucho sentido tener una frase:

```
anita lava la tina
```

y obtener como salida la misma frase:

```
 anita lava la tina
```

**Lo que necesitas es una forma para determinar si la frase o palabra es o no palíndroma** y esto lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

```
String myPhrase = "anita lava la tina";
//Normaliza palabra
myPhrase = myPhrase.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "").replace(",","");       
int counter = 0, longWord = myPhrase.length()-1;
boolean isError = false;

while ((counter<longWord) && (!isError)){
    if (myPhrase.charAt(counter) == myPhrase.charAt(longWord)){             
        counter++;
        longWord--;
    } else {
        isError = true;
    }
}
if (!isError){
    System.out.println(myPhrase + " : es un PALÍNDROMO :-)");
}else{
    System.out.println(myPhrase + " : NO es un PALÍNDROMO :-(");
}
```